# DrEdit - Test the application : Deployment Successful but unable to create text file and could not able to see User's Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I want to run DrEdit code and I have successfully deployed my dredit eclipse application onto the Google App Engine.

I downloaded DrEdit from [git repositories](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/java), 
Followed all the steps in the readme file along with

1. Created my app on google drive console,
2. Got client id and client secret, replace ones in DrEdit,

I can see the consent screen and after accepting that, I am assuming that I could create a file and I could see that file in my google drive. But nothing is happening.

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Dredit</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.csus.dredit.DrEditServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dredit</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dredit</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartPageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.csus.dredit.StartPageServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StartPageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/start</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.csus.dredit.FileServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/svc</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.csus.dredit.UserServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AboutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.csus.dredit.AboutServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AboutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>start</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
  <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>profile</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
         </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

What is wrong in the DrEdit code? I haven't change anything in it.

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)). A good question never has thanks, greetings or a name below it.

Comment: Anthon, If you know the answer, please reply.

Comment: Does anybody know answer for my question. It is a showstopper for my project. I need to integrate my code into dredit. If I am unable to test and run dredit, I can not integrate my project into it. I am okay to know how the ideal flow of dredit. Right now, I am only be able to see the consent screen. Moreover, when I am looking at the code, I see that DrEditServlet doesn't have doGet(). Can anyone help me understand how is the flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lots of struggle, I can be able to see exact output of DrEdit application. Here is what I did-

1. I already have downloaded the original DrEdit code from the Git repositories. I compared the index.html from the java folder and php folder, and saw many changes. So went ahead and copied the php index.html into my java application in Eclipse. This helped in integrating all the .css and .js into the index.html.
2. The resources locations were missing in my Eclipse application, so figured that out.
3. I don't know why but I wasn't able to see the exact output in Chrome. So tried in IE, I have IE 11 installed on my machine. 
   By implementing all the above mentioned steps, I can now able to see the exact output of the DrEdit application.

I must say that when I was reading posts here about DrEdit for php, it gave me so much hints about where I was making mistakes, what to look for, what to change, configurations, other intra-files settings, all I learned here. This knowledge helped me in making DrEdit for java, a fully functional application.